# How are sharps and flats written in the Nashville Number System?

Tags: notation, accidentals

How are sharps and flats written in the Nashville Number System?  5♯ or 5♭?

Answer (score 3):

Sharps and flats should be written as you guessed, after the number and using ♯/♭ notation. However, in common usage, some musicians use the flat symbol before the note rather than after it while still using the sharp symbol afterwards, e.g. ♭5 and 4♯.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashville_Number_System):

> Accidentals modifying a scale degree are usually written to the left of the number. ♭7 ("flat 7") represents a B♭ major chord in the key of C, or an A♭ major chord in the key of B♭, or an F major chord in the key of G.

[Music Theory for Musicians](https://www.music-theory-for-musicians.com/nashville-number-system.html) also indicates the accidental comes before the number, though giving only the example of b7.

All other sources consulted, if they addressed accidentals at all, only addressed b7.